# Declaring certain elements as const in an array c++, sudoku solver

Tags: c++, sudoku

Is it possible for me to take an existing array and make certain values (not all) constant? I'm trying to build a sudoku solver and my idea is to have the user enter values, so I would like to have those values remain constant as I change the empty spaces. Any tips or advice with the solver would also be appreciated. This is my first quarter working with c++. Thanks!

Comment: You have to take care yourself not to change the fields you consider as constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Const is essentially a compile-time idea. It's not something that can be toggled as a program is running.

If you need certain values to remain untouched while others are changed, then you need to put that into your data and logic. For instance, each value might have an associated boolean that indicates whether or not it can be changed. Then write your logic to respect that boolean.